# ERR_PNPM_CONFIG_CONFLICT_LOCKFILE_ONLY_WITH_NO_LOCKFILE Cannot generate a pnpm-lock.yaml because lockfile is set to false

Tags: npm, pnpm

I deleted the pnpm-lock.yaml file so that i get the latest dependency
ran the pnpm i command so that new pnpm-lock.yaml with the latest dependency  gets generated.
but unfortunately pnpm-lock.yaml did not generate

Can some one help on this?

Answer (score 3):

Issue got resolved.

for some users pnpm set the lockfile config to false
hence reset that config using the below command

```
pnpm config set lockfile=true
```

And try running the below command

```
pnpm i --lockfile-only
```